# Muay Thai: Halfway - pivot roundhouse kick

Tags: training, technique, muay-thai, kickboxing

What is the name of the Muay Thai kick, where the person only rotates halfway on ball foot, and pivots less to not gain reaction from opponent? There was a name for it, if it was "axe kick", or feint kick. One of my coaches had the specific Muay thai name with written Thai language. can't remember.

I am thinking its "diagonal kick" after looking on youtube, not sure, interesting to note these differences.

https://youtu.be/ChB-nomLGQg?t=296

[image]

Comment: I am thinking its "diagonal kick" after looking on youtube, not sure